# ORA-02256: referencing foreign key

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm a SQL newbie and having some troubles with referencing a foreign KEY

My Event Table:

```
create table Event
(
Bookid  number(5),
edate date,
FacID int,
GuestID int,
CONSTRAINT pk1edate PRIMARY KEY (edate,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT fk1Bookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid),
CONSTRAINT fk2FacID FOREIGN KEY (FacID) references CUSTOMER (SponsorID),
CONSTRAINT fk3GuestID FOREIGN KEY (GuestID) references CUSTOMER (SponsorID)
);
```

and my event_register table

```
create table EVENT_REGISTER
(
CID number(6),
Bookid  number(5),
edate date,
CONSTRAINT pk1Edate PRIMARY KEY (edate,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT fk2Bookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK,
CONSTRAINT fk3edate FOREIGN KEY (edate) references Event (edate,Bookid)
);
```

I get this error when I try to run the Event_Register:

```
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify all the columns in both parent and child tables while referring.

```
create table EVENT_REGISTER
(
CID number(6),
Bookid  number(5),
edate date,
CONSTRAINT pk1Edate PRIMARY KEY (edate,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT fk2Bookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK(Bookid),
CONSTRAINT fk3edate FOREIGN KEY (edate,Bookid) references Event (edate,Bookid)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also I just noticed I made a mistake of the naming of the primary key. I named both of them pk1edate which also gave an error. Again thanks for your help!